# Return value from nested http.put

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-http

How to return response object from http.put to controller as return value from TestFunction? 
response from http.get is printed OK but putResponse is undefined. During debug I can see that http.put updates data on server.

```
  testFunction: function (url, data) {
        var etag;
        var putResponse;
        $http.get(url).then(function successCallback(response) {
            if (response.data != null) {
                etag = response.headers(['etag']);
                 $http.put(url, data, { headers: { 'If-Match': etag } }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                     putResponse = response;
                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    // handle error
                });
            }
            else {
                // handle error

            }

        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            // handle error

        });
        console.log(putResponse);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$http.get` and `$http.put` are executed asynchronously from the rest of the code.
you have that `console.log` out of the async call. so it gets called before the return.

Furthermore If you want the `putResponse` returned to the "caller" you have to return both `putResponse` and the promise:

```
  testFunction: function (url, data) {
        var etag;
        var putResponse;
        var promise = $http.get(url).then(function successCallback(response) {
            if (response.data != null) {
                etag = response.headers(['etag']);
                return $http.put(url, data, { headers: { 'If-Match': etag } })
            }
            else {
                // handle error
                // $q.reject();    
            }

        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            putResponse = response;
            console.log(putResponse); // this gets called after the server responds ( defined ) 
            return putResponse;
        })
        ["catch"](function (response) {
                 // handle error
        });

        console.log(putResponse); // this gets called before the server responds ( undefined )
        return promise;
    }
```

now you can use

```
tesFunction(arg1, arg2).then(function(response){ /* in here you have response defined */ })
```

Comment: thanks, testFunction is OK now, console output for putResponse is OK too. I was unable to return putResponse to the caller with 
testFunction(url,data).then(function(response){ /* in here you have response defined */ }) ... only response from get is displayed?

Comment: yes you are right I have updated my answer.  this way the if else inside the get has to also return a promise or you will have an error.

Comment: Yes, this will do the trick! response is returned successfully to the caller.
To summarize: first you have to return putResponse and then the promise   and with catch you have to handle error from put.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to use `$q.all()` to return multiple promises.

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sscovil/waxL8Lt8/

In that example, I am using an `$httpProvider` interceptor to mock the HTTP responses; that is not relevant to what you need, just necessary for illustration.

The important bit is the `myRestService` function:

```
function myRestServiceFactory($http, $q) {
  return function() {
    var deferredGet = $q.defer();
    var deferredPut = $q.defer();
    var promises = {};

    promises.get = deferredGet.promise;
    promises.put = deferredPut.promise;
    $http.get('https://example.com').then(onGetSuccess, onGetError);

    return $q.all(promises);

    function onGetSuccess(response) {
      if (response.data != null) {
        var etag = response.headers(['etag']);
        var config = {
          headers: {'If-Match': etag}
        };
        $http.put('https://example.com', {}, config)
          .then(onPutSuccess, onPutError);
        deferredGet.resolve(response);
      } else {
        deferredGet.reject(response);
      }
    }

    function onGetError(error) {
      deferredGet.reject(error);
    }

    function onPutSuccess(response) {
      deferredPut.resolve(response);
    }

    function onPutError(error) {
      deferredPut.reject(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that it uses `$q.defer()` to create two promises, then returns `$q.all(promises)`. This returns a single promise that you can attach a callback to via `.then()`, and the callback will receive a map of promise responses like this:

```
function MyController($scope, myRestService) {
    $scope.values = {};
    myRestService().then(function (values) {
      $scope.values.get = JSON.stringify(values.get);
      $scope.values.put = JSON.stringify(values.put);
  });
}
```

Comment: This is another way to do it. So far I was avoiding using $q.defer but after your explanation looks so easy! 
By your opinion which approach is the best(easier) yours or the one above(without using $q)?

Comment: Which is easier? That's subjective. But I think my approach is easier to follow when reading the code.

Comment: Nice approach! The difference is that in this you return both promises in mine you have only. Readability relies only in naming the anonymous functions imo, which you can do in both approaches.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. Thought the OP wanted both resolves.